# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n^2-n+3}{n^2+3n-4}\right)^n\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n} \left(x>0\right)$ Convergence/Divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Convergence/Divergence of
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n^2-n+3}{n^2+3n-4}\right)^n\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n} \left(x>0\right) \end{aligned}\end{equation*}

Let $a_n=\left(\frac{n^2-n+3}{n^2+3n-4}\right)^n\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^n}$, Then
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{n^2-n+3}{n^2+3n-4}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x}} \cdot\frac{x}{(1+x^n)^\frac{1}{n}}. \end{aligned}\end{equation*}

(1)、 If $0 < x < 1$ , then by $1 < 1+x^n < 2$, we have
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned} \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x^n)^\frac{1}{n}=1\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=x < 1. \end{aligned}\end{equation*}
By ratio comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

(2)、What about the case $x\geq 1$?

Comment: Make $n=1$ to see a problem from the start

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$${n^2-n+3\over n^2+3n-4}\le 1,\qquad n\ge 2$$
(a) For $0<x<1$ and $n\ge 2$
$$0<\left ({n^2-n+3\over n^2+3n-4}\right )^n{x^{n-1}\over 1+x^n}\le x^{n-1}$$ By the comparison test
we get convergence.

(b) For $x\ge 1$ we have
$$\left ({n^2-n+3\over n^2+3n-4}\right )^n{x^{n-1}\over 1+x^n}\ge \left ({n^2-n+3\over n^2+3n-4}\right )^n{2\over x}$$
We are going to use the Bernoulli inequality
$$(1-x)^n\ge 1-n x,\qquad x\le 1$$
Consider $n$  divisible by $8.$ Then
$$\displaylines{\left ({n^2-n+3\over n^2+3n-4}\right )^n=\left (1-{4n-7\over n^2+3n-4}\right )^n =\left [\left (1-{4n-7\over n^2+3n-4}\right )^{n/8}\right]^{8}\\ \ge \left (1-{4n^2-7n\over 8(n^2+3n-4)}\right )^{8}\to {1\over 2^8}}$$
Therefore the terms of the series of the form $n=8k$ do not tend to $0.$
Hence the series is divergent for $x\ge 1.$

**Remark** Actually for $x\ge 1$ all terms are bounded away from $0.$ To this end we can apply the generalized Bernoulli inequality
$$(1-x)^\alpha\ge 1-\alpha x,\quad x\le 1, \ \alpha\ge 1$$
with $\alpha=n/8$ for $n\ge 8.$